# php-casperjs getting inner text

Tags: php, dom, casperjs

I'm using the php wrapper for casperjs - https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs

I'm automating some repeative jobs on the web, and I need to access the innerText of an item, but it isn't entirely clear to me how to access the dom from the casperjs browser.

I think in js I would us

```
var arr = document.querySelector('label.input__label--above').innerText;
```

However I'm nt sure how to access the same array from the php wrapper?? I've managed to fill forms and navigate to the page I want with a couple of lines of code, but accessing the dom doesn't seem obvious at all.

My wrapper is called $casper so I've been using

```
$casper->start("google.com")
```

as an example, which should put me on google page, if I then wanted to access the dom, and eventually some innerText can anybody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is done through `evaluate` in PhantomJS and CasperJS. php-casperjs does provide an `evaluate` function, but it isn't applicable to your use case, because `$casper->evaluate` doesn't return anything from the page context but rather a reference to `$casper`.

This is the price of having such a small wrapper. It simply lacks a big part of CasperJS. You could write CasperJS script as it is intended with JavaScript and invoke it from PHP with `exec` or some other similar function.

You could however also try to extend `$casper` with a function that returns the `textContent` through a callback (note that `innerText` is not available in PhantomJS). It has to be done through a callback because of the asynchronous nature of CasperJS. I'm not entirely sure this is possible, without rewriting large portions of the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks I'd previously done this with Javascript and using the exec function as you suggested, but I was trying to bring it all under one roof so to speak, as PHP is my preferred language for this sort of thing. This is the only wrapper I've found so far, so I might have to so stick the the mixed javascript and php approach unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference for anybody else struggling with ways to achieve this, I trawled through the code for the wrapper, and the html from the final page in the script, is returned as part of an array when you execute

```
$result = $casper->run()
```

Hope this helps others.